# Injection from $\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{Z}^+)$ to the set of total orders on $\mathbb{Z}^+$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

My goal is to prove that $\mathcal{T} = \{$ R|R is a total order on $\mathbb{Z}^+ \}$ is equinumerous with $\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{Z}^+)$ by applying Cantor-Bernstein. Since $\mathcal{T} \subseteq \mathscr{P}(\mathbb{Z}^+\times \mathbb{Z}^+)\sim \mathscr{P}(\mathbb{Z}^+)$, $\mathcal{T} \precsim \mathscr{P}(\mathbb{Z}^+)$, so all that's left is finding an injection from $\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{Z}^+)$ to $\mathcal{T}$, but my attempts on constructing one or finding a set $X$ such that $X \sim \mathscr{P}(\mathbb{Z}^+)$ and $X \precsim \mathcal{T}$ lead to nothing. Could someone provide some useful hints or post a solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given a subset $A$ of $\Bbb Z^+$ and its complement $B$, consider the linear order obtained by placing all the elements of $B$ on top of the elements of $A$.

(This is not injective, but there is exactly one problem to be solved.)

(As a challenge, find a way where this one problem is mitigated without using special cases.)

Comment: You just have to be able to distinguish $\varnothing$ from $\not-$: the integers are *heavy*. `:-)`

Comment: There's actually a neat way to overcome this problem without "special cases". But it's easy to show it like this.

Comment: Brian, I had an... opposite half... idea in mind. :-)

Comment: Could you maybe explain what you mean by "place on top"? My first guess would be $A \times B$, which can be extended to a partial order and that partial order likewise to a total order, but unfortunately I still don't know how to proceed...

Comment: @Amjad: It's closer to $\{0\}\times A\cup \{1\}\times B$ ordered lexicographically.

Comment: Okay, thank you! I'll post another comment if I need further help :)

Comment: Got it! Special cases can be omitted if we define the function you hinted at only for $A \subseteq \mathbb{Z}^+ \setminus \{1\}$. Then, since $\mathbb{Z}^+ \setminus \{1\} \sim \mathbb{Z}^+$, $\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{Z}^+) \precsim \mathcal{T}$, which finishes the proof. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I used $f: \mathscr{P}(A) \rightarrow \mathcal{T}$ defined by $f(X) = (Y \times W) \cup L_{Y} \cup L_{W}$, where $A = \mathbb{Z}^+ \setminus \{1,2\}$, $Y = X \cup \{1\}$, $W = (A \setminus X) \cup \{2\}$, $L_{Y} = \{(x,y) \in Y \times Y \mid x \leq y\}$, and $L_{W} = \{(x,y) \in W \times W \mid x \leq y\}$.

Comment: I checked this function (tedious but not hard) and it looks correct. Basically,check that (i) the function always outputs total order and (ii) the function is injective.

Comment: I tried with $f:\mathscr{P}\left(A\right)\to\mathcal{T}$ defined by $f\left(X\right)=\left(X\times Y\right)\cup L_{X}\cup L_{Y}$, where $A=\mathbb{Z}^{+}\setminus\left\{ 1\right\}$, $Y=\left(A\setminus X\right)\cup\left\{ 1\right\}$, $L_{X}=\left\{ \left(x,y\right)\in X\times X\mid x\leq y\right\}$, and $L_{Y}=\left\{ \left(x,y\right)\in Y\times Y\mid x\leq y\right\}$. And it worked.